# Removing default image size list in Media Box

Tags: functions, images, media, list, filters

[image: Removing default image size list in Media Box]

I trying to remove unused image size (Thumbnail, Medium, Large) in MediaBox

Any function can i use in functions.php ? or some trick ?

PS : I know i can use jQuery trick but any better function to use ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exactly the same code as Mridul, but different filter:

```
function wp_70048_remove_image_sizes($sizes) {
    unset($sizes['thumbnail']);
    unset($sizes['medium']);
    unset($sizes['large']);
    return $sizes;
}
add_filter('image_size_names_choose', 'wp_70048_remove_image_sizes');
```

Tested with WP 3.4.2
[image: removed image sizes]

Comment: @brasofilo This only applies to **default** images. Do you know a solution to unset custom image sizes? I've opened a question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95344/disable-custom-image-sizes-from-media-library

Answer (score 1):

```
function remove_default_image_sizes($sizes) {
    unset($sizes['thumbnail']);
    unset($sizes['medium']);
    unset($sizes['large']);
    return $sizes;
}
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'remove_default_image_sizes');
```

Comment: nope , cant do with this :(