# Hide custom image sizes from media library

Tags: php, images, filters, media-library

I want to hide a few custom image sizes from the media uploader:

[image]

The following code ([posted here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70048/removing-default-image-size-list-in-media-box)) works **only** for the default image sizes:

```
function remove_image_sizes($sizes) {
    unset($sizes['image-name']);
    return $sizes;
}
add_filter('image_size_names_choose', 'remove_image_sizes');
```

Is there a similar solution to unset custom image sizes?

Comment: I thought it was the other way around and that you had to ***include*** custom sizes in that dropdown (using the global `$_wp_additional_image_sizes`). :::: Ain't no extra code somewhere in your set-up including the extra sizes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `unset` and `intermediate_image_sizes_advanced` will work but only on images uploaded **after** the function is added. To change it for existing images you need to regenerate them using a plugin ( in essence deleting that image size) or just hide that option from being visible.

Tested on 3.5.1

```
// add custom image size
function mytheme_95344() {
        add_image_size('x-la',800,800, false);
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_95344' );

// remove it
function remove_image_size_95344($sizes) {
    unset($sizes['x-la']);
    return $sizes;
}
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'remove_image_size_95344');
```

So this `x-la` size will still show for images before the `unset` function was added.

To remove this you can.

1. Regenerate all images (a pain).
2. Hide it from the display using `image_size_names_choose`

   ```
   function remove_image_size_95344($possible_sizes) {

    unset( $possible_sizes['x-la'] );
    return $possible_sizes;

   }  
   add_filter('image_size_names_choose', 'remove_image_size_95344');
   ```

---

*To clarify the filters*:

`intermediate_image_sizes_advanced` - effects the actual upload
`image_size_names_choose`  - effects the visibility of the dropdown in the media box

*Also note*:

It could be that a theme or plugin is already using the `image_size_names_choose` filter somewhere since it is very common when using `add_image_size` for custom images. If that is the case you can still use a second `image_size_names_choose` filter and set the `$priority` to fire **after** the first one.

```
 //default filter adding your custom sizes to dropdown
 // not having a 3rd parameter will default to priority of 10
 add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_insert_custom_image_sizes' );
 //second use of same filter to remove images note the additional 15 to fire after the above
 add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'remove_image_sizes', 15);
```

To view how filters work: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter

Comment: My tests show that `intermediate_image_sizes_advanced` works but removes the upload, which I don't want. So I tested `image_size_names_choose` like this: http://pastebin.com/Gfngy1TQ and then uploaded a new image but the sizes are all visible in the drop-down. Is there a reason why `image_size_names_choose` doesn't work? Can you please double check that it works for you?

Comment: Ahh I found an instance when I use `image_size_names_choose` in my code, please view: http://pastebin.com/b0xD8DfP So that may be the reason why this is not working? You mentioned something about setting priorities to fix this? How would I go about doing that? Can you please demonstrate using my code...

Comment: Works like a charm! I understand now why there were such a confusion between us. Originally, I wrote that I want to disable image sizes from the drop-down list, when in fact, I wanted to hide them. I chose the wrong word for my question which lead me to be confused by you are proposing that I disable (remove) the sizes. :) So my sincere apology for the confusion and thank you for hanging in there. This is a great answer that will be helpful for others too.

Comment: No worries, it is pretty confusing, this post helped me remember how it works:)